# How to increment 4 rows with formulas in Excel by one cell reference at a time

Tags: excel

I'm trying to build a script where each cell value from Sheet1 B2:B3000 is referenced 4 times on Sheet2.

Example of desired output

```
=concatenation "Text & Sheet1!B2"
=concatenation "Text & Sheet1!B2"
=concatenation "Text & Sheet1!B2"
=concatenation "Text & Sheet1!B2"

=concatenation "Text & Sheet1!B3"
=concatenation "Text & Sheet1!B3"
=concatenation "Text & Sheet1!B3"
=concatenation "Text & Sheet1!B3"
```

But if I use this pattern and fill down it will always jump 4 rows incorrectly like this

```
=concatenation "Text & Sheet1!B2"
=concatenation "Text & Sheet1!B2"
=concatenation "Text & Sheet1!B2"
=concatenation "Text & Sheet1!B2"

=concatenation "Text & Sheet1!B6"
=concatenation "Text & Sheet1!B6"
=concatenation "Text & Sheet1!B6"
=concatenation "Text & Sheet1!B6"
```

Any idea how I can force a single increment per block of 4 commands please?

Answer (score 0):

Try `INDIRECT()` function-

```
="Hello " & INDIRECT("B" & ROUNDUP(ROW()/4,0))
```

[image]